# Difference between Resize and SizeChanged events

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

In C# .Net in Winforms, 
I found two events in almost all components, Resize() and SizeChanged().
Is there any difference between them?
If both events are the same then why has C# provided two different events?

I am creating a user control in C#.  This control contains a text box. 
I want to resize the textbox when the user changes the control's size.
I am confused about which event I should use and why?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `Resize` event occurs when the control is resized, while the `SizeChanged` event occurs when the `Size` property changes.

You could use either, as a resize will cause the `Size` property to change. However, you should rather use the `Layout` event, as recommended both in the documentation for the [Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize.aspx) and [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged.aspx) events.

Comment: But Layout doesn't occure when a resize my control

Comment: @Haider Ali: That's odd. The event is triggered "when the bounds of the control changes" according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.layout.aspx

Comment: yes, you are right this link is really helped me, this is exactly what that I am looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great tip on LayoutChanged should be preferred!

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes these answers only come from the source code:

#### SizeChanged

The [`SizeChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event is raised by the [`OnSizeChanged()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onsizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx). This function is in turn only called by `UpdateBounds()`, which is called by several mechanisms, primarily including the handling of [`WM_MOVE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652(v=vs.85).aspx) messages.

Again from the source, `OnSizeChanged()` will only be called when `UpdateBounds()` has determined that there is a difference between the *old size* and *new size*. So, yes, as the others have already determined, the `SizeChanged` event corresponds to the `Size` property changing.

#### Resize

The [`Resize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.110).aspx) event *is* different, but not by much. It is raised by [`OnResize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onresize(v=vs.110).aspx). This function is called as a direct result of `OnSizeChanged()`. However, the reverse is not true. That is to say, `OnResize()` ***DOES NOT*** call `OnSizeChanged()`.

The difference lies in the perspective from which you uses these API's. If you are merely subscribing to these events, then there is virtually no difference. Either way you look at it, whenever the control's size is changed, both events fire.

However, if you are inheriting `Control`, one must be aware of the following differences:

- `OnResize()` will *invalidate* the control if the style, [`ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) is set.
- `OnResize()` will trigger a layout with the [`AffectedProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.layouteventargs.affectedproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) set to `"Bounds"`.

The reason why one might care, for instance, is to make sure that their logic is executed before the base implementation (and hence before the invalidate) to be properly drawn to the screen.

#### LocationChanged and Move

These are two move events that parallel `SizeChanged` and `Resize` almost identically. The exceptions are that `OnMove()` only invalidates when the style, [`ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) is *true* and the backcolor is a less than opaque alpha value. And, `OnMove()` will not trigger a layout.

Again this difference likely only matters to control authors.

#### Conclusions

After investigating into the source code, my conclusion is that the `Resize` and `Move` events are an *abstraction* away from the property changed events, and would likely be the preferred choice for both subscribing and overriding these specific events.

As others mention, the [`Layout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.layout(v=vs.110).aspx) event and [`OnLayout()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) function are also a decent choice; however, layouts can occur in many instances:

- When child controls are added/removed.
- When the bounds of the control changes.
- When ***other changes*** occur that can affect the layout of the control.

  > <sup>***Side Note:*** *"Other changes" is vague, but I assume that Microsoft is referring any action taken by inheritors that require a layout.*</sup>

Relying too strongly on layout events may slow down your code/control since they will occur more frequently than a simple resize event would. Or, it is possible that the layout engine might be suspended by [`SuspendLayout()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx), In this case, you will not be able to react to size changes via the `Layout` event.

Answer (score 13):

[So what IS the difference between the Resize and the SizeChanged events?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/12/450822.aspx)

> Believe it or not *absolutely* nothing.  One method calls the other. 
>   However because the latter is named "Changed" it can be used for data
>   binding - so while I dont have any concrete proof, that's my theory on
>   why both exist.

Comment: yes, that is right, Size is a property and for every property .Net has provided an event for <propertyname>changed event so sizechanged event is associated with its property for data binding. thank you for response

Comment: Well, I found it to be rather different: If I change the Image/BackgroundImage at the end of the `Resize` event it just doesn't work, as if I had aborted the event. If I move the same code to the `SizeChanged` everything works as expected.