# Relation of .NET Layout events

Tags: .net, winforms, events, layout

Does there exist a concise tree or map showing which form events are triggered by which other events?

ex: `Control.SizeChanged` calls `Control.Layout` but does `Control.BackgroundImageChanged` call `Layout` or `BackgroundImageLayout`?  etc.

The reason I ask (which shouldn't matter) is:
I'm attempting to catch several events related to form resize, move and images changing.
I don't want to doubly handle events that microsoft decided to create too many events for such as [`control.resize` and `control.sizechanged`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441431/difference-between-resize-and-sizechanged-events).

Comment: Or even a list of triggers for the `Control.Layout` event would be nice. Microshaft says Layout occurs when "[changes occur that can affect the layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.layout.aspx)."