# What is the difference between Form.Move and Form.LocationChanged?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

If you create a standard C# WinForms application, you fill find that a form has two events: `Move` and `LocationChanged`.

`Move` is raised when the form moves and `LocationChanged` is raised when the form `location` property changes.

Surely if the form moves, the location property will change, too?

What is the difference between the two events? In which case will one fire and not the other?

Comment: Related: [Difference between Resize and SizeChanged events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7441431/4934172).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Move` and `LocationChanged` events are interconnected. I believe there is no situation when one if fired and the other is not. The difference is that they belong to different categories of events.

The `Move` event has `[SRCategoryAttribute("CatLayout")]` attribute.

The `LocationChanged` event has `[SRCategoryAttribute("CatPropertyChanged")]` attribute.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I did not even know that there were event "categories". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `Move` and `LocationChanged` events are declared on the `Control` class, which is then inherited by `ScrollableControl`, `ContainerControl` and finally `Form`.

According to the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/control.cs,8c31b9e4b00e1cba,references), `OnLocationChanged` calls `OnMove` ***before*** it invokes the `LocationChanged` event handler. So, the `OnMove` event will be raised first and *then* `LocationChanged`. You could in theory handle both events knowing that `Move` will be occur first.

If you look through the source you'll see that `LocationChanged` is raised when the bounds change (or similar events). You'll also notice that **the only thing** which actually invokes `OnMove` is in fact `OnLocationChanged`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.locationchanged(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks), the `LocationChanged` event:

> Occurs when the Location property value has changed.... This event is
>   raised if the Location property is changed by either a programmatic
>   modification or through interaction.

It makes [no such distinction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move(v=vs.110).aspx) for `OnMove`, where it merely states:

> Occurs when the control is moved.

Which is curious since the two events are tied to each other.

This is however how one specific class handles these events. I did a bit of searching through the reference source and I couldn't find anything (inheriting from `Control`) which explicitly called `OnMove` other than the instance I've already cited. That doesn't mean they don't exist or that one couldn't invoke it separately in their own subclass of `Control`.